# I want to open drop down menu on hover.I have created that and it opens on hover but when I want to select option from menu it close suddenly

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to open drop down menu on hover.I have created that and it opens on hover but when I want to select option from menu it close suddenly.How do I open drop down on hover?On hover I want to open it and and on hover on options also want to open it.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {margin-left: 6px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:first-child {margin-left: 0;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;color:#fff;display:block;font-size:17px;font-weight:400;padding:30px 10px;text-transform:uppercase;overflow: hidden;transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {color:#FFFFFF;background:#fbba00;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active:after {opacity: 1;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a i{font-size:2em;color:#fff;margin-left:2px;line-height: 0;margin-left:4px;position: relative;top:5px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover i{color:#fff;}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.drop:hover .dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown li, .sup-dropdown li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.dropdown li:first-child, .sup-dropdown li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}

.dropdown li a, .sup-dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding:8px 14px;
    font-weight:400;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}


.dropdown > li:hover > a, .sup-dropdown li:hover > a {
    padding-left: 18px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#373d43;
}

.dropdown li a i {
    margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .sup-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li.drop .dropdown li:hover .sup-dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown" >
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Get started<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a <?php if(!is_page('home')){ ?>  href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" <?php } else { ?> id="anchor" <?php }  ?> >SITE FINDER</a></li>

                            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/resources/">LOCAL ADVERTISING GUIDE</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" >
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">adnozzles<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/adnozzles/">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/testimonials/">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/test/gallery/">GALLERY</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: My site link is:http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/test/

Comment: I have added:- .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

Comment: are you trying promote your site or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the space between your navigation link and your list (.dropdown-menu).

Change your margin-top css of .dropdown-menu to 0 and it will work:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px; // add some padding, so you keep the same style
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You could flag this answer as solution for your problem ("check accept answer"), thx :)

Comment: how to flag this answer?